# Updating node labels to avoid clutter in JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit (JIT)

Tags: javascript, jit, infovis

I am doing visualization with the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/), in particular the [hypertree](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Hypertree/example1.html). I am loading data dynamically and sometimes the labels around the nodes overlap and clutter. I would like to avoid this clutter by altering the label positions.

Here is an example of cluttering (the top and bottom nodes):

[image: JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit clutter]

I imagine that I would loop through each x,y coordinate, give it some bounding box and do basic collision detection, and update positions accordingly.

For this library, I see the demo shows a onPlaceLabel() function, but (if I understand correctly) at that moment I wouldn't know the position of every other node's label. So, I am looking at onComplete(), where I see I can access each node as follows:

```
onComplete: function(){
     ht.graph.eachNode(function(n) {
        console.log(n);
    }
}
```

But the node information does not include its label positions, only their positions relative to the center node. Is there a way to access the labels in this way and be able to update their positions?